# Select min start and max end for consecutive periods in SQL Server 2012+

Tags: sql-server, partitioning, gaps-and-islands

I have a table in SQL Server 2012 with events log in a format like this:

```
+=====+=============================+=============================+======+
| ID1 |       start_time_utc        |        end_time_utc         | ID2  |
+=====+=============================+=============================+======+
|  57 | 2018-11-11 11:00:00.0000000 | 2018-11-11 11:00:28.0012900 |   15 |
|  57 | 2018-11-11 11:00:28.0012900 | 2018-11-11 11:01:29.0543947 | 1020 |
|  57 | 2018-11-11 11:01:29.0543947 | 2018-11-11 11:02:28.1923079 |   16 |
|  57 | 2018-11-11 11:02:28.1923079 | 2018-11-11 11:04:28.3367626 |   16 |
|  57 | 2018-11-11 11:04:28.3367626 | 2018-11-11 11:05:28.5307626 | 1020 |
| 103 | 2018-11-10 20:00:00.0000000 | 2018-11-11 03:00:00.0000000 |   15 |
| 103 | 2018-11-11 03:00:00.0000000 | 2018-11-11 10:57:00.8175737 |   15 |
| 103 | 2018-11-11 10:57:00.8175737 | 2018-11-11 10:57:27.8322749 | 1017 |
| 103 | 2018-11-11 10:57:27.8322749 | 2018-11-11 11:00:00.0000000 |   15 |
| 103 | 2018-11-11 11:00:00.0000000 | 2018-11-11 11:00:31.9916890 |   15 |
+-----+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+------+
```

For a given ID1, end date has a matching start date of the next event. I want to partition the data by matching ID1 and ID2 columns, and select start date and end date for each partition of consecutive events. So the result should be:

```
+=====+=============================+=============================+======+
| ID1 |       start_time_utc        |        end_time_utc         | ID2  |
+=====+=============================+=============================+======+
|  57 | 2018-11-11 11:00:00.0000000 | 2018-11-11 11:00:28.0012900 |   15 |
|  57 | 2018-11-11 11:00:28.0012900 | 2018-11-11 11:01:29.0543947 | 1020 |
|  57 | 2018-11-11 11:01:29.0543947 | 2018-11-11 11:04:28.3367626 |   16 |
|  57 | 2018-11-11 11:04:28.3367626 | 2018-11-11 11:05:28.5307626 | 1020 |
| 103 | 2018-11-10 20:00:00.0000000 | 2018-11-11 10:57:00.8175737 |   15 |
| 103 | 2018-11-11 10:57:00.8175737 | 2018-11-11 10:57:27.8322749 | 1017 |
| 103 | 2018-11-11 10:57:27.8322749 | 2018-11-11 11:00:31.9916890 |   15 |
+-----+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+------+
```

I obviously can't use simple group by and don't know how to write the partition by query. Thanks for help.

Comment: Do you have some kind of column to check if this is next event or previous event ? I just wanted to understand if there is a field like that it would be easier. I was trying to order by Start date with the same ID1 and ID2 , but looking at your output I don't think it can be done with dates.

Comment: @Avi: no, the only next/previous is per start and end times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an updated version that works for dataset given and also handles cases where you have sequences of id1,id2 greater than 2 in all cases i have tested for. It is much simpler than my original answer. Replace tstGrouping with your table name.

```
;with p as
(
  select
   ROW_NUMBER () over (order by id1, start_time_utc) as row_num,
   ROW_NUMBER () over (order by id1,id2, start_time_utc) as row_num2,
    *
  from
    tstgrouping x1
)
select 
  id1,
  min(start_time_utc) as start_time_utc,
  max(end_time_utc) as end_time_utc,
  id2
from p
  group by
row_num - row_num2,id1,id2
order by 
id1, start_time_utc
```

Comment: Works great, thanks. Nice and simple. I earlier tried to overcomplicate by trying to join end time to the next start time. This approach doesn't care if end time has a matching start time, correct?

Comment: I also overcomplicated it on first try, this doesnt really care about times it just exploits the fact that consecutive id1,id2 pairs will have the same row offsets when ordered by id1, start_time and id1,id2, start_time

Answer (score 0):

```
;with base as
(
Select *
,row_number()over(partition by id1, 1d2 order by start_time_utc asc) ordstart
,row_number()over(partition by id1, id2, order by end_date_utc desc) ordend
)

Select * from 
base b1
inner join base b2 on b1.id1 = b2.id1 and b1.id2 = b2.id2 ans b1.ordstart = b2.ordend
Where b1.ordstart = 1
```

Comment: Done from my phone and untested, but I’m pretty sure this should work.

Comment: quick test says this answer filters out too many rows, only one of each id1, id2 combo is returned.

Comment: Good call. So you’ll have to join the cte to itself on b1.start_time = b2.end_time and compare the ids with a case statement. Might have run a while loops as I dont believe there is a limit on how many consecutive id pairs can exist. Im sure there will be, but if there’s not an accepted answer by tomorrow morning, I’ll put something together on break at work.